# How to extract certain part of the text into another file?

Tags: regex, perl, text, extract

Here is my code. I wish to extract part of the text and write into another file. The loop of the code do not stop at my selected range of text. It read until the final match line of word. Please advise me. Thanks. For example, I need to extract the $ NAME: sandy until $$.TO and then join with the contents inside $NAME: patrick which is start from G1 until $$SRU.

TEXT:

```
$ NAME : corry  
$$.Inc s d
$$.Oc s
$$.TO

G1 ty n1 EE EE M T1 T2 $$SRU
G2 n1 y OO OO M T3 T4 $$SRU    
$$.EON

$ NAME : patrick    
$$.Inc c d
$$.Oc c
$$.TO

G1 td n3 EE EE M T5 T6 $$SRU      
G2 n3 y OO OO M T7 T8 $$SRU    
$$.EON
$ NAME : sandy    
$$.Inc k l
$$.Oc l
$$.TO

G1 td n3 FF FF M R5 R6 $$SRU      
G2 n3 y OO OO N R7 R8 $$SRU    
$$.EON
```

OUTPUT:eg.

```
$ NAME : sandy    #from sandy section
$$.Inc k l      #sandy
$$.Oc l         #sandy
$$.TO           #sandy
G1.G1o.n ty n1 EE EE M T1 T2 $$SRU #from Patrick section
G2.G2o.n n1 y OO OO M T3 T4 $$SRU   #Patrick 
Fe.id.n ty n1 EE EE N T1 T2 $$SRU #corry
Fr.in.p n1 y OO OO N T3 T4 $$SRU   #corry 
$$.EON     #Patrick
```

CODE:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $F1, '<', 'testing.txt' or die "failed $!";
open my $F2, '>', 'out.txt' or die "failed $!";

while (<$F1>) {
 if (/^\$ NAME : sandy/../\$.TO/) {
 print $F2 $_;
 }
 if (/^\$ NAME : patrick/../\$.EON/) {
 if(/^G1/../\$SRU/){
 s/G1/G1.G1o.n/g;
 print $F2 $_;}
}

 }
close $F1;
close $F2;
```

Comment: Your program doesn't seem incorrect for me, unless the typo in closing the pattern of `/\$SRU/`. What output do you expect?

Comment: I have update the desired output. Have a look.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse all the file to one big hash, and do everything you want with its elements: combine, change etc

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

open my $F1, '<', 'in' or die "failed $!";
open my $F2, '>', 'out.txt' or die "failed $!";


my %elements;
my $current_element;
while (<$F1>) {
    if ( /^\$ NAME : (\w+)/ .. /\$\$[.]EON/ ) {
        if ( /^\$ NAME : (\w+)/ ) {
            $current_element = $1;
        }
        if ( /^G1/ ) {
            $elements{$current_element}->{g1} .= $_;
        }
        elsif ( /^G2/ ) {
            $elements{$current_element}->{g2} .= $_;
        }
        elsif ( ! /\$\$[.]EON/ ) {
            $elements{$current_element}->{text} .= $_;
        }

    }
}
close $F1;
$elements{patrick}->{g1} =~ s/G1/G1.G1o.n/;
$elements{patrick}->{g2} =~ s/G1/G2.G2o.n/;
$elements{corry}->{g1} =~ s/G1/Fe.id.n/;
$elements{corry}->{g2} =~ s/G2/Fr.in.p/;
print $F2 "$elements{sandy}->{text}$elements{patrick}->{g1}$elements{patrick}->{g2}$elements{corry}->{g1}$elements{corry}->{g2}\n\$\$.EON";
close $F2;
```

this will parse all the file to hash that looks like:

1. $elements{'name (for example patric'}->{text} = 'everithing in patric section except G1 and G2 section'
2. $elements{'name (for example patric'}->{g1} = 'G1 section'
3. $elements{'name (for example patric'}->{g2} = 'G2 section'

so if you want to combine `text` from sandy and `G1` from patric you can do

```
my $sandy_patric = $elements{sandy}->{text}.$elements{patrick}->{g1};
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. when I attached the `my $sandy_patric` into the code, error pop out.` Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at try line 24, <$F1> line 57.`

Comment: is it the error uninitialized value in concatenation(.) if mistype name?

Comment: first of all this is not error. this is warning. this warning means that you try to access variable, that is not initialized yet. there was no `$elements{patric}` variable.

Comment: Can I skip warning? I understand what you say about the warning, when I modified it into another name, this error still exist.

Comment: Warning means that something goes wrong. You can ignore it, programm will not die. Warnings causes errors in future) I will update my answer to full code without warnings

Comment: your code works great so far.Thanks for the help. If i use the same hash concept to read the value for T5, for eg, in the input text file, stated `T5=2.8`, how i read the value and substitue it byitself without manual. Any idea?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualgcer chapter

Comment: your code works great so far.Thanks for the help. If i use the same hash concept to read the value for T5, for eg, in the input text file, stated `T5=2.8`, how i read the value and substitue it byitself without manual. Any idea? Use hash?
` if(/T5= (.*)/){
$val=$1;
 s/T5/$val/g;
}`?

Comment: I dont understand what you want to do with this code. What is `T5`, `2.8` here? And you really need to learn more about regular expressions. Start with searching `regular expressions perl` in google.

Comment: T5 is assign to a parameter value, where i did not include the text here. T5 is equal to 2.8,what i wish to do is it will assign to this value automatically. I really need to learn more about regular expressions. Thanks very much for your help and time and advise. I truly appreciate it. It is my first Perl assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You were not far from a solution. I would set a flag when inside the `patrick` section I find the line that begins with `G1`, and I would save each line in an array (after substitution) to append it after processing the `sandy` section:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my (@patrick, $flag);

open my $F1, '<', 'testing.txt' or die "failed $!";
open my $F2, '>', 'out.txt' or die "failed $!";

while ( <$F1> ) { 
    if (/^\$ NAME : sandy/../\$\.TO/) {
        print $F2 $_; 
    }   
    if (/^\$ NAME : patrick/../\$\.EON/) {
        if ( m/\AG1/ ) { $flag = 1 } 
        if ( $flag ) { 
            s/\A(G\d+)/$1.$1o.n/;
            #print $F2 $_;
            push @patrick, $_; 
        }      
    }   

}

print $F2 $_ for @patrick;

close $F1;
close $F2;
```

It will create a file `out.txt` with content:

```
$ NAME : sandy    
$$.Inc k l
$$.Oc l
$$.TO
G1.G1o.n td n3 EE EE M T5 T6 $$SRU      
G2.G2o.n n3 y OO OO M T7 T8 $$SRU    
$$.EON
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Would you mind explain this following?
`if ( m/\AG1/ ) { $flag = 1 } 
        if ( $flag ) { 
            s/^(G\d+)/$1.$1o.n/g;
            #print $F2 $_;
            push @patrick, $_; 
        } `

Comment: how to modified this `s/^(G\d+)/$1.$1o.n/g` to suit all kind of substitution alphabet?

Comment: would like to ask another question which is if i want to get corry section content with G1 into the output text as well, how should i do it?

Comment: @annel: It's basic `perl` code. `m/.../` is a regex pattern, and the same for `s/.../.../`. Take a look to them in `perlre` documentation. That code sets a flag to indicate which part of section I want to extract. For `corry` section the approach is the same. Save them in another array and print to output file at the end of the script.